# Как привязаться к событию обновления значения свойства?

Tags: битрикс

Есть функция [CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update();](http://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=iblock&name=CIBlockPropertyEnum%3A%3AUpdate)
Она по себе не имеет событий. Есть ли возможность с использованием D7 как-то отлавливать момент изменения значения свойства?

Comment: уточните чтоо именно вы делаете. приведите свой код в котором вы вызываете `CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update()`

Comment: @NikolajSarry Я ничего не вызываю. Мой вопрос исчерпывающий, я хочу дабы если любой пользователь/сам битрикс использует вызов `CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update();` я смогу отследить это изменение.

Comment: И для чего? Просто так? Ответ касательно `CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update()` в первом предложении моего ответа. На данный момент нет АПИ для отслеживания этого метода.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно для `CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update()` в API на данный момент событий нет.

Но есть события обновлений свойств инфоблока [`OnAfterIBlockPropertyUpdate`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onafteriblockpropertyupdate.php) и [`OnBeforeIBlockPropertyUpdate`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockpropertyupdate.php).

По методам изменяющим свойства через API есть только [`OnIBlockElementSetPropertyValues`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/oniblockelementsetpropertyvalues.php) и [`OnIBlockElementSetPropertyValuesEx`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/oniblockelementsetpropertyvaluesex.php)

Ну и на крайняк есть события обновления элементов инфоблока [`OnIBlockElementUpdate`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/oniblockelementupdate.php), [`OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockelementupdate.php), [`OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onafteriblockelementupdate.php).

Comment: Зачем мне список этих функций. У меня вопрос конкретно об обновлении значения свойства типа список.

Comment: @Oleksandr пишите вопрос так чтобы получить в ответе, то что вам нужно. Насчет отслеживания событий через `CIBlockPropertyEnum::Update()` я ответил первым предложением. На данный момент для него в АПИ нет событий. Но момент изменения свойства можно отловить и событием изменением элемента. Либо изменяйте значения через `SetPropertyValuesEx` тогда вы сможете отслеживать по событию обновление свойства.